# An exercise in fuzzy logics built from a t-norm

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, lo.logic, model-theory, boolean-algebras, modal-logic

Consider the following t-norm:

$$   
a * b = \begin{cases}
       2ab, &\quad\text{if }a, b\le1/2\\
       \min\{a, b\} &\quad\text{otherwise}
      \end{cases}
$$

We build from it the $\langle [0, 1]_*, \{1\}\rangle$ matrix logic as usual. Thus, the resulting R-implication and associated negation are:

$$
a \rightarrow b = \begin{cases}
       1 &\quad\text{if } a \le b \\
       b/2a &\quad\text{if }1/2\ge a>b\\
       b &\quad\text{if } a > b \text{ and } a > 1/2
      \end{cases}
$$

$$   
¬ a = \begin{cases}
       1 & \text{if } a = 0\\
       0 & \text{otherwise}
      \end{cases}
$$

As usual, $\wedge$ is the minimum and $\lor$ is the maximum.

For this logic, I need to prove the following implication, for any formulas $\phi$ and $\psi$:

$ \phi \rightarrow \phi * \phi, \phi \models \psi$ implies $ \phi \rightarrow \phi * \phi \models \phi \rightarrow \psi$

This is equivalent to showing the following:

if for any $[0, 1]_*$-interpretation I, we have $I(\phi) = 1 \Rightarrow I(\psi) = 1$

then for any $[0, 1]_*$-interpretation I, we have $I(\phi) \ge 1/2 \Rightarrow I(\psi) \geq I(\phi)$

Comment: Please do not ask the same question on both MO and MSE, at the same time. Doing so puts both communities to work, when a single one could do the job, thus wasting our efforts. If you do not get an answer on MSE, wait for a few days before asking again on MO. Also, please link to the question on the "other" site, it helps us to see what answers or at least coments it has received.

Comment: @AlexM. Okay, noted! Sorry and thank you for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

My teacher has provided a solution:

Take a $[0, 1]_*$-interpretation with $I(\phi \rightarrow \phi * \phi ) = 1$, and say $a:=I(\phi)$.

Define the function \begin{align*}
h: [0, 1] & \rightarrow [0, 1]\\
x&\mapsto \begin{cases}
       1 &\quad\text{if $x \geq a$}\\
       x &\quad\text{if $x < a$}
      \end{cases}
\end{align*}

We can check this function preserves all of the connectives of the logic. So $h \circ I$ preserves connectives and is thus a $[0, 1]_*$-interpretation. And $h \circ I (\phi \rightarrow \phi * \phi) = h \circ I (\phi) = 1 $, so by our supposition $h \circ I (\psi) = 1$ and thus $I(\phi) \leq I(\psi)$.